# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'submit_args' referenced before assignment -Pyspark

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am very new to Pyspark. I am using Anaconda to execute a piece of Pyspark code. I am trying to initiate SparkContext .This is throwing the error listed below. Looks like this error is quite normal in Python, but I am unable to figure out in the context of Pyspark.
The code is like this:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
import random
import os
import sys
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Pi")
```

Just executing this is throwing an error which is like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-3fc08890af27> in <module>()
----> 1 sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Pi")

C:\opt\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    113         """
    114         self._callsite = first_spark_call() or CallSite(None, None, None)
--> 115         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

C:\opt\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    278         with SparkContext._lock:
    279             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 280                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    281                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    282 

C:\opt\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf)
     58                 submit_args
     59             ])
---> 60         command = command + shlex.split(submit_args)
     61 
     62         # Start a socket that will be used by PythonGatewayServer to communicate its port to us

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'submit_args' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Can you try removing the app_name parameter. Also are you using standalone spark or did you `pip install pyspark`?

Comment: Even After removing the parameter it is the same.
I have done the pip install pyspark .

Comment: then why are you using findspark?

Comment: I was following a tutorial . It was running fine yesterday.I am trying the same steps today but it failed.

Comment: There could be a bug, can you uninstall this pyspark package and install `pip install pyspark==2.12`